# Instantiate business entity without losing encapsulation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have a `Customer` business entity in `Domain` project, I want to instantiate it in `DomainService` project based on its properties. There are business logic that needs enforcement when it is created, e.g. `Salary` depends `FirstName` (example only). I don’t want its setters being public which loses encapsulation.

How to instantiate/initialize it without losing encapsulation. The setter's private can be changed, not public.

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        public string Firstname { get; private set; }

        public string Surname { get; private set; }

        public decimal Salary { get; private set; }
        //... other properties
    }
```

Comment: You might find this blog post on designing entities interesting: http://www.jefclaes.be/2013/04/designing-entities-immutability-first.html

Answer (score 3):

If your requirement is that strict on encapsulation.. then your only real option (that I can think of right now) is using the constructor:

```
public Customer(string firstName, string surname, decimal salary, ...)
```

It isn't a sin to allow direct manipulation of a domain object like this. If you're that worried about what might happen.. either give them backing fields or have your entity expose a public interface for making changes to them (which could perhaps use some sort of `Guard` class to determine validity).

Comment: The ctor is the best spot for protecting invariants.

Comment: I wrap DateTime.Now, I need to validate DateOfBirth within Customer entity using DateTimeWrapper, But I cannot using dependency injection, because the constructor is like above. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there are two scenarios you will create a Customer instance.

A: Retrieving an exsiting **Customer** from **Repository**. In this case you don't need to enforce the constraints when considering they were validated before the **Customer** was stored to the **Repository**.

B: A brand new **Customer**. You can use a **Factory** to encapsulate the creation if there are some important domain constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If your validation can work at the `Customer` level, suggest adding a property, say `IsValid` which runs the business rules on the `Customer` object. Couple of implementations could be as follows:

```
public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Firstname) && Salary > 0;
    }
}

public Dictionary<string, string> IsValid2
{
    get
    {
        var errors = new Dictionary<string, string>(); //TODO: Instantiate only if errors are found

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Firstname))
        {
            errors.Add("ERR_001", "First name is invalid.");
        }

        if (Salary <= 0)
        {
            errors.Add("ERR_002", "Salary should be a positive number.");
        }

        return errors;
    }
}
```